# Slowly removing blur on background image after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

So, using html, css, javascript, I am looking for a way to have it so that my page will load with the background image blurred. Then, after the whole page loads, the image slowly goes from being fully blurred to being not blurred at all. Not an instant blur to crisp, but I nice transformation.

Not sure if I would have to have a blurred picture and one thats not and just somehow switch the pictures slowly? Any tips would help.

Comment: what have you archived so far..?

Comment: Will not post it as answer, since IE10 and IE11 aren't covered (you can use this for older IE's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but works like a charm in normal browsers (firefox, chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/vqkftdeo/

Answer (score 1):

Blurring sounds like a nice job for Canvas.
Maybe have a look at http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
You can put your canvas page-wide on your screen with something like:

```
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0px;
}
```

Then draw your background-picture blurry (have a look at the hyperlink) on it, and use setInterval or something like that in order to unblur it gradually.

Comment: This looks perfect. So I would have to download the source on the page and link to that?

Comment: I guess so. You could also link directly to the online source, but then you're dependent on that site, so I would indeed reccomend downloading the source and "including" it in your HTML (with a `<script src="blur.js"></script>`) BEFORE your own code (because if you put it after your code, the blur-functions might be only available after your own code has ran.

Comment: Since CSS provides a native blur effect (as mentioned in the comment), using javascript is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to be able to blur the `background-image` using a CSS hack. Usually, I would just set the `opacity` property of a container, but that would effect everything in the container. What I did instead was use the `:before` pseudoclass to toggle only the background-image.

```
#myContainer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#myContainer:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.1;
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCFyJhwDi5ud74pENDaCIuggegz89q6Odhke5IEo7vEKwjewDxsQ);
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59zutyLd/1/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

To remove the blur, you could use the jQuery animate property for something like this

```
$("#myContainer:before").animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 2000)
```

Unfortunately, pseudoclasses are not part of the DOM, so they can't be used in jQuery.

Comment: Wouldn't that just fade in the entire body over 2 seconds?

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. That just makes everything but the background look clear (like its barely there) and slowly fade that into the screen. I'm saying actually having an image blurry to the point you cant really tell what is it and transforming the blurry picture into a crisp clear picture.

Comment: http://tkgenius.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/blurry-and-clear.jpg     This is what Im really looking for. This type of blur

Answer (score 0):

Keep the **background_div** with **position:relative**

Create a **overlay div** inside that and keep it as **position:absolute, opacity:0.5, full width, full height.**

Apply **fadeout effect on overlay** div 
I hope it will the expected output.

Try the demo here:

```
     [1] https://jsfiddle.net/fnwL8ozg/3/
```

Comment: As with Richard Hamilton's answer, this is only a fade effect, while the desired effect is a blurring effect.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but what you are looking for is "Blur Up" technique described here: https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/

TLDR:

1. You create very small size copy of original picture
2. You load that first and add Gaussian blur overlay so it doesn't seem bad
3. On download complete with basic JavaScript you change pic with original
4. Add transition to blur none and profit